# math.random always give 0 result

Tags: java, random

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and I am studying Java from the book. I tried to follow one example on the book with Ubuntu Terminal and I'm using Sublime Text. Here is the code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RepeatAdditionQuiz{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int number1 = (int)(Math.random()%10);
        int number2 = (int)(Math.random()%10);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print(
            "What is "+number1+" + "+number2+"?");
        int answer = input.nextInt();

        while(number1+number2 != answer){
            System.out.print("Wrong answer. Try again. What is "
                 +number1+" + "+number2+"? ");
            answer = input.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("You got it!");
    }
}
```

But the problem is, when I compiled it and executed it. It gives me result

> what is 0 + 0?_

every time. It suppose to give me random number, and yes, it can be 0. But I tried to run it more than 10 times, it keeps giving me 0 + 0, when it's suppose to random from 0-9.

The result of 0 + 0 is fine when I typed 0 as a result, it gets me out of the loop

Did I miss something to make the math library works? How can I fix the randomize issue?

Comment: Did you bother to read the documentation or use Google to find any examples?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Math.random()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) returns a double value between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). It does not return an integer value. Therefore, when you take the number produced by `Math.random()` modulo 10, it returns the same double value. The final cast to `int` makes that value always 0.

Run the following code to see for yourself:

```
double random = Math.random();
System.out.println(random); // for example 0.5486395326203879
System.out.println(random % 10); // still 0.5486395326203879
System.out.println((int) (random % 10)); // outputs 0
```

What you really want is to use a `Random` object and use [`Random.nextInt(bound)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-). To have a random integer between 0 and 9, you can use:

```
Random random = new Random();
int value = random.nextInt(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Math.random();
```

Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

This is the problem. You need to then multiply with 10, so you get a number between 0 and 10 and after that you can cast to int.

Comment: But if I got 0.99 and I mulitply it by 10, I will first get 9.99. This is why I said you will get a number between 0 and 10. Do you agree? After that when you cast it to an int then you will get a number between 0 and 9, this way you are right.

Comment: Ok I see, it was not clear for me that this is what you meant

Answer (score 1):

> `public static double random()`
>
> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.

([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29))

It returns a double that satisfies `0.0 <= double < 1.0`, therefore taking the modulo will always result in zero. I recommend the [`java.util.Random`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class to achieve what you need. Specifically [`Random.nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

The [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--) method returns a random `double` that is from 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive).  Performing `% 10` doesn't affect this value, but casting it to an `int` truncates any decimal portion, always yielding `0`.

If you want a random number from `0-9`, you can multiply `Math.random()` by `10`, instead of taking the remainder when divided by `10`.

Alternatively, you can create a `java.util.Random` object and call [`nextInt(10)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-).

Answer (score 0):

Read the doc :

> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to
>   0.0 and less than 1.0

Therefore, you will always get less than 1, and the cast to `int` will round it down to 0. Use, for example, a `Random` object which has a `nextInt(int max)` method :

```
Random rd = new Random();
int number1 = rd.nextInt(10);
int number2 = rd.nextInt(10);
```

Comment: Why downvoting me ? The answer is accurate

Answer (score 0):

Math.random() returns a number greater or equal than 0 and less than 1.
What you are looking for is either

```
 int number1 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
 int number2 = (int)(Math.random()*10);
```

or

```
 Random rand = new Random();
 int number1 = rand.nextInt(10);
 int number2 = rand.nextInt(10);
```

Also, to get random number from given range, use this for Math.random()

```
int number 3 = min + (int)(Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1))
```

and for random.nextInt()

```
int number 4 = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Math.random()` method returns a Double value between 0 and 1, so you will never get a number greater or equal than 1, you will ever get a value that could be 0, but never 1. And as you are taking the residual from this value over 10, you will ever get a 0 as result.

`Math.random() % 10` will always be 0, because the random method gives you `0 <= value < 1`, and when the `% 10` operation takes place, you will get 0.

[Check here for more details](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) (oracle documentation)

Answer (score -1):

Math.random gives a double value between 0 (incl.)-1 (excl.)!